# How to increase the bounty being offered?

Tags: bounty

Even though it is not 100% true, I believe that increasing the bounty can stimulate others to help. :-) Is it  possible to increase the bounty being offered?

Comment: This question should be asked on the meta site (meta.tex.stackexchange.com). Probably a moderator can move it for you there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to increase a bounty. Though only one bounty may be active, it's possible to add another (possibly higher) bounty to the same question after the previously active bounty ran out.

See Jeff's blog post: [Improvements to Bounty System](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/).